# font,font size, and color change javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am trying to make this code change the pre-written text font, font size, and color with an onclick button but am unable to make it work this is what i have so far and im stuck. anyone have any ideas?

```
<html>
  <head> 
      <meta charset=utf-8 /> 
      <title>Change Paragraph Text</title> 
  </head>  
  <body> 
      <p id ='text'>I am going to change this text, I hope.</p>  
      <div>
        <button id="jschange" onclick="DoAll">Style</button> 
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var style = 'text';
         function DoAll() {
            One(document.write.style.big());
            Two(document.write.style.fontsize(7));
            Three(document.write.style.fontcolor("red"));
         }
      </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Seriously, where did you learn about `style` with `document.write`?

Comment: teaching my self for class so various websites that apparently are telling me the wrong thing from you are suggesting lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="style-target">This is the element which will change.</p>
    <button id="change-styles">Change Styles</button>
    <script>

      window.onload = function () {
        var changeStyles = query("#change-styles");
        var target = query("#style-target");

        changeStyles.onclick = function () {
          style(target, "fontSize", "18px");
          style(target, "color", "blue");
          style(target, "fontWeight", "bold");
        };
      };

      function style (el, property, value) {
        el.style[property] = value;
      }

      function query (selector) {
        return document.querySelector(selector);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have a look;

I've taken the liberty of adding the rest of the "required" HTML bits and pieces, there (especially the DOCTYPE). You don't need to know what it's there for, right now, but it will solve a lot of problems in the future, if you always include it at the top of every HTML page you write, if you intend real people to use that page (basically, it makes Internet Explorer < IE10 suck less).

I've broken this down into bits that are a little more sensible, in terms of real-world JavaScript.

In most programming languages, you want to break your code down into smaller bits, to make it easier to read and work with.
JavaScript isn't really much different.

I have broken apart apart the act of setting the style, into its own helper function

```
el.style.color = "purple"; // takes `el` and makes an el{color:purple} rule
```

The catch here is that any CSS "style" that has a hyphen ("font-size", "background-color") needs to use camelCase, when setting the value in JavaScript.

```
el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

I've created a helper function called `style`, which I then refer to inside of my `window.onload` code.

In this particular case, I'm not saving a lot, in terms of what I'm typing (in fact, I'm typing more), but what it would be saving me, in a more complex case, is the chance of missing something, in repeating myself, or in copy/pasting...

So by calling `style(el, "fontWeight", "bold");` I don't have to remember how to set the style for old-browsers, versus new browsers, versus styles that have been set using JS earlier on, versus those that haven't (a topic for people concerned with professional websites that have to work on ancient browsers).

If you look inside of the definition for `style` that I wrote, you'll see that I'm calling `el.style[property]`; normally, when we know the name of the thing we're looking for, on an object, we use a dot to separate them `person.name; //"Bob"`.
In circumstances where we might want to look for different properties, we use `[<property-name>]` to separate them.

var property = "age";
   person[property]; // 32

Next, I am using `document.querySelector( selector );` to find the elements that I want, by passing it a CSS-style selector.

`document.querySelector` works on practically all browsers made in the past 6 years.

I'm grabbing the element I want to change the styles of, and I'm grabbing the element I'm listening to (waiting for a user to click).

Then I'm setting the `onclick` of the button to a function which will fire off a bunch of changes that I specify.
In this case, the onclick will change some styles.

You don't typically want to use `onclick` or similar properties; normally, you want to use a process called `event-registration` or "listening", but that goes a little too far, for such a simple example.

For now, grab the elements, separate your "how you do it" implementation details from "when 'X' do 'Y'" runtime details, and watch magic happen.

Funny enough, this isn't much more code than the jQuery suggestion provided in another answer...

...but that's a whole, gigantic library that you'd have to load (if you were even allowed), just to select a thing and change its styles.
Also, by using the "jQuery solution" to common problems, you frequently learn bad habits, or alternatively, don't learn good habits which you would need to learn, had you not had the quick and easy solution in front of you.
jQuery, as used by most people, is particularly bad about reference-caching (or a lack thereof).  If widely used jQuery patterns are employed on a production website, without thought put into them (especially if you're not using jQuery, but some other library like it), you can murder your website's performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a much simpler approach and won't make anyone's eyes bleed:

```
<button onclick="restyle()">Click me to see some results</button>

<p id="changeable">Text that will change.</p>

<script>
   function restyle() {
      var element = document.getElementById("changeable");
      element.style.fontsize(7);
      element.style.fontcolor("red");
      element.innerHTML = "changed text";
   }
</script>
```

I'm still learning Javascript too, so if there are any experts out there I'd love to hear what they think! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p id ='text'>I am going to change this text, I hope.</p>  
     <div>
       <button id="jschange" onclick="DoAll()">Style</button> 
     </div>

    <script>
      function DoAll() {
        $('#text').css('font-size', '7').css('color', 'red');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead that js code:

```
var sstyle = 'text';
function DoAll() {
   var elem = document.getEelementById(sstyle);
   elem.style.fontSize = "7px";
   elem.style.color= "red";
}
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to display a string in a specified size.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = "Hello World!";
            var result = str.fontsize(7);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.